# Deserializing PHP Data from Web service

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization

I'm receiving data from a web service. The data are in the following format:

```
a:5:{s:7:"request";s:14:"94.190.179.118";s:6:"status";i:206;s:12:"currencyCode";s:3:"BGL";}
```

I need to parse the input.

Can you advise me what format is this and what is the easiest way to parse them?

...

I can parse by splitting the string by ';' and to search the individual elements for the wanted key and the following value. (possible, but bad solution)
Probably the data are serialized in a standard format and can be deserialized in a dictionary.

Comment: Is that even a standart data format?

Comment: It's not XML and Json. I hope someone will recognize it. Probably 'a' means count of records. s - length of the following string, i - integer..

Comment: Any documentation on this "format"? Why not ask the supplier to provide data in a more standard format?

Comment: Yes. I'm facing the same issue. Its PHP serialized data coming from a web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is PHP's own serialization format. Try [Sharp Serialization Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csphpserial/) to read this in.

Comment: Hi Anton, Its not working. 
Its de serializing data, but output result is not getting any of the value and also most of the key values are missing...

Answer (score 5):

This looks like serialized PHP: http://php.net/serialize

PHP includes built in deserialize methods. As for C#, there might be 3rd library somewhere that will do this for you.

My advice would be to see if you can have the API communicate in a standardised format such as JSON or XML. Failing that, you will need to convert it from a serialized string, to usable object data in C#.