# Convert serialised php object to nested json

Tags: c#, json, associative-array

I would like to change a JSON format from:

```
a:3:{s:10:"modulename";s:6:"assign";s:10:"instanceid";s:1:"3";s:4:"name";s:18:"Assignent_test_two";}
```

to:

```
{"modulename":"assign","instanceid":"3","name":"Assignent_test_two"}
```

Any thoughts in doing it through C# or Python

Thanks

Comment: First string is not valid json

Comment: First doesn't look like valid json. And yes I have various thoughts how to convert. What was yours?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, check and reformat the question to provide more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing PHP Data from Web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861855/deserializing-php-data-from-web-service)

Comment: As people noticed it's not a Json input. First we have to find what is this format. Googleing "a:size:{ serialize"   tell me that it's a [php serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). With this information finding the duplicate is quite simple.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your reply. It is a log format from moodle site, you are right it is php serialised using json_encode(). I need to extract the data in this format and convert into flat csv.  my technology choices are very limited  to either c# , sql or USQL. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You input string is a [PHP Serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) result. With the following format:
`a:size:{key definition;value definition;(repeated per element)}`.
Array value are either integers or strings. Here we will asume it's always string.  Based on this rules, we can find the value with `:"(\w+)";`.

```
string pattern = @":""(\w+)"";";
string input = @"a:3:{s:10:""modulename"";s:6:""assign"";s:10:""instanceid"";s:1:""3"";s:4:""name"";s:18:""Assignent_test_two"";}";

var originalArray = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
                         .Cast<Match>()
                         .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
                         .ToArray();
// -> {"modulename", "assign", "instanceid", "3", "name", "Assignent_test_two"}
```

We have to select value from this original data array , 2 by 2, to compose the dictionary:

```
var projectionToExpectedResult =
            Enumerable.Range(0, originalArray.Length / 2)
                     .ToDictionary(i => originalArray[i * 2], j => originalArray[j * 2 + 1]);
```

Serialising the disctionary give the expected result:

```
var serilisedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(projectionToExpectedResult);
// -> {"modulename":"assign","instanceid":"3","name":"Assignent_test_two"}
```

If if there were `int` data in the input file. They will look like `i:1;s:5:"value";`. The regex will be `:"?(\w+)"?;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `string.Split()` because it is not looking like a json

ex-

```
string jsonNew = "{";
string jsonString = "{s:10:\"modulename\";s:6:\"assign\";s:10:\"instanceid\";s:1:\"3\";s:4:\"name\";s:18:\"Assignent_test_two\";}"   // I have Escaped string assuming you are getting the same 
var strArr = jsonString.Split(';');
foreach(var str in strArr){
    var attr = str.Split(':')[2];
    if(jsonNew[jsonNew.Length-1] == ":"){
        jsonNew = jsonNew + attr + ",";
    }
    else if(jsonNew[jsonNew.Length-1] == ","){
        jsonNew = jsonNew + attr + ":";
    }
}
if(jsonNew[jsonNew.Length-1] == ","){
   jsonNew[jsonNew.Length-1] = "}";
}
```

I think something like this can be done to parse the above string into json. Tell me if the idea works